# What is the difference between a permutation group and a symmetric group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, definition, symmetric-groups

> What is the difference between a permutation group and a symmetric group?

I know such questions asked before on Math Stack Exchange, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/permutation-groups-and-symmetric-groups#:%7E:text=A%20symmetric%20group%20on%20a,of%20elements%20on%20the%20set.).

But I would appreciate it if someone could spell out the difference without discussing group actions.

Comment: Each subgroup of a symmetric group is called a permutation group

Comment: We have ${\rm Sym}(X)=\{ f\colon X\rightarrow X\mid \text{f is a bijection}\}$ for a set $X$. If $X=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$, then it is called $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ letters. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) spells it out without discussing group actions. In the same way, look up permutation group in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group).

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Why would anyone vote it down?

Comment: Given a positive integer $n$, the set of all permutations of $n$ things forms a group, under composition, called the symmetric group $S_n$. So, the symmetric group is a group of permutations. Also, it follows that every subgroup of the symmetric group is (or can be viewed as) a group of permutations. Indeed, every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, so every finite group can be viewed as a group of permutations.

Comment: The answer is very simple: a permutation group is a subgroup of a symmetric group.

Answer (score 4):

A symmetric group on a set $X$ is the set of all bijections on $X$ (called permutations) under the operation of function composition.

A permutation group is a subgroup of a symmetric group. Be careful, however, because Cayley's Theorem states that every group is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of a symmetric group; so to be clear: a permutation group is a group of permutations, not necessarily equal to a symmetric group.

---

For example, $G=(\{e, (13)\}, \circ)$ is a permutation group, since it is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_3$. But $H=(\{1,-1\},\times)\cong G$, despite $H$ not being a permutation group.